# Multiplying every element in a set by a number

Tags: python

What is wrong with the following code?

```py
set_ = {1, 2, 3, 1}
set_ * 2
```

I'm looking to produce:

```py
{2, 4, 6}
```

Why does multiply not work for set in this way?

Comment: On my Python3 installation your example raises a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a set comprehension. You can't use broadcasting-like syntax on Python sets:

```py
{item * 2 for item in set_}
```

This outputs:

```py
{2, 4, 6}
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicates are not allowed in sets.

```
>>> set_ = {1, 2, 3, 1}
>>> set_
{1, 2, 3}
```